# Как вывести содержимое последних 10 записей в таблице MySQL?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Как вывести содержимое последних 10 записей в таблице MySQL, а потом добавить кнопку, которая будет выводить эти последние 10 записей + 10 последних записей перед этими 10 записями? И на кнопку можно нажимать бесконечно и записи будут выводится пока не будут выведены все. Думаю что понятно объяснил. Это как вконтакте, в новостях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в MySQL есть очень удобный ограничитель, который осуществляет как раз вашу задачу:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE условие 
LIMIT 120,20
```

Первый параметр у LIMIT  - сколько записей пропустить, второй -  это количество отдаваемых записей. (Если выборка отдала меньше записей, чем первый параметр, то результат будет пустым).

Устанавливая эти числа переменными вы сможете управлять выводом.
Например:

```
$records_on_page = 20; // 20 записей на странице
$from = $records_on_page * $page; // $page - номер страницы (0 - первая, 1- вторая...)

$SQL  ="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $condition LIMIT  $from, $records_on_page ";
```

"последние 10 записей" - некорректное условие. Что значит "последние"?
откуда считать? Какая сортировка? А может просто условие сортировки поменять и не мучить себя вычислением общего количества записей вообще? И выводить первые 10... :)

Answer (score 2):

По сути - это тот же постраничный вывод/постраничная навигация, только вместо кнопок страниц используете одну и внутренний счетчик для смены порции записей. Используйте LIMIT для ограничений и DESC для вывода начиная с последних записей.

Comment: Хех, спасибо, буду смотреть